# Scrollable Div/Window in Windows 8 (Scroll View)

Tags: windows-8, scrollview, winjs

I'm using WinJS (JavaScript) to create a Windows 8 app.

I wish to make a container, either a DIv or something else, that I can put content in to and can be used for scrolling by touch.

I've looked at flex box, but that appears to be just for Internet Explorer?

Am I missing something?

This is my markup so far, I want to make the wrapper scrollable

```
<div id="wrapper">


    <div class="login_box">

        <form method="post">
            <label class="login_label">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" class="login_input" name="login_username" />
            <label class="login_label">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" class="login_input" name="login_password" />
            <input type="submit" id="login_submit" name="login_submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is this done via CSS?

Comment: Most anything that works in IE works in Windows 8 HTML/JS apps as well. They both use the same engine, so the behavior you'll get from the HTML markup, CSS properties, and (with some safety exceptions) the JavaScript should be identical. You can use a single div or you could use a flexbox if you have multiple things that you wanted to scroll through. See http://codeshow.codeplex.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For WinJS, you can add the .win-scrollview class to your wrapper div and then use the overflow-x and overflow-y css properties to control scrolling behavior.

Comment: Actually, the .win-scrollview itself sets overflow-x and overflow-y, so all you should have to do is set .win-scrollview I believe.